# Need to change the parameter value in the url

Tags: javascript

trying to add/change the values of the parameters in the url, but can't able to change/add the values

trying to add/change the values of the parameters as shown below
var Filename ='abc.pdf';
var strUser='john';
var url = '@Url.Action("Action","Controller", new{ filename="name", username="User" })';
window.location.href = url.replace('name',Filename + 'User', strUser);

but not able to do it

Comment: you can use  `params.set()` method to update the existing parameter.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var url = new URL('http://demourl.com/path?id=100&topic=main');
var search_params = url.searchParams;

// new value of "id" is set to "101"
search_params.set('id', '101');

// change the search property of the main url
url.search = search_params.toString();

// the new url string
var new_url = url.toString();

// output : http://demourl.com/path?id=101&topic=main
console.log(new_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
var downloadUrl = '@Url.Action("Download", "File", new { filename = "default.pdf", username = "default" })';
var Filename = 'abc.pdf';
var strUser = 'john';
var url = downloadUrl.replace('default.pdf', Filename).replace('default', strUser);
window.location.href = url;
```